# An elegant way to do this? May be generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I have two derived classes (Sale and ServiceCharge). Both are Transactions. If I have a BusinessService, I want to create a ServiceCharge for it. If I pass a Product, I want to instantiate Sale.

Here's my idea.

```
private void CreateInstance(object element)
{
    Transaction transaction;
    if (element.GetType() == typeof(BussinessService))
    {
        transaction = new ServiceCharge((BussinessService)element))
    }
    else
    {
        transaction = new Sale((Product)element);
    }
{
```

Could you tell me a more elegant way? I would know how to use generics with only a single constructor

```
private void CreateInstance<T>(T element)
{
   Transaction transaction = new Transaction((T)element);
}
```

But I don't know how to work out with the first case.

Comment: element should be polymorphic. Because element is poorly named I can't offer a code based fix.

Comment: are `BuisinessService` and `Product` polymorphic in some way? Do they implement a common interface or share a common ancestor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a plain interface would also work in this case:

```
interface ITransactionable
{
    Transaction CreateTransaction();
}

class BusinessService : ITransactionable
{
    public Transaction CreateTransaction() { return new ServiceCharge( this ); }
}

class Product : ITransactionable
{
    public Transaction CreateTransaction() { return new Sale( this ); }
}
```

---

```
private void CreateInstance(ITransactionable element)
{
   Transaction transaction = element.CreateTransaction();
   ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Yep, that's true. There's nothing in the code OP showed which needs it to be generic. This is a bit simpler, but interface names in .NET [should start with an `I`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229040.aspx).

Comment: I agree.  I think the generics makes it more complicated without adding any value.

Comment: I was tempted to suggest this as an answer but generics can give you a specialised return type which could be beneficial.

Comment: That's true, but also not specifically needed here. The reason I went for the simple polymorphic solution was based on the idea that simpler is better if it achieves what's required! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I need to train my poor OOP abilities. This solution is giving me a lot of new ideas :)

Comment: @SteveL, agreed, the best design is bourne of necessity. Everything else is superfluous.

Answer (score 6):

Define a generic interface like this:

```
public interface ITransactionable<T>
    where T : Transaction
{
    T CreateTransaction();
}
```

And decorate your `BussinessService` and `Product` as:

```
public class BussinessService :
    ITransactionable<ServiceCharge>
{
    public T CreateTransaction() 
    { 
        return new ServiceCharge(this);
    }
}

public class Product :
    ITransactionable<Sale>
{
    public T CreateTransaction() 
    { 
        return new Sale(this);
    }
}
```

Now your generic method can be defined as:

```
private void CreateInstance<T>(ITransactionable<T> element)
{
   Transaction transaction = element.CreateTransaction();
   ...
}
```

Comment: one critisicm, its not covariant. Otherwise we've arrived at the same answer. Although I prefer my semantics I can't read the OP's mind.

Comment: if the interface is not covariant, you'll have trouble making an `IEnumerable<ITransactionable<Transaction>>` which would obviously be useful for set based operation or any polymorphic linq activity.

Comment: Perhaps name it `ITransactionableFactory` as this is looks like the Factory Pattern

Answer (score 1):

Just create two different methods:

```
private void CreateInstance(Product product)
{
    Transaction transaction = new Sale(product);
}
private void CreateInstance(BusinessService service)
{
    Transaction transaction = new ServiceCharge(service);
}
```

The compiler will know what method you called depending on the type of the parameter you use.

Answer (score 1):

`BusinessService` and `Product` should be polymorphic in some way, probably by sharing a interface, somthing like

```
interface IChargable<out T> where T : Transaction
{
    Transaction Charge();
}
```

The interface implemented thus,

```
class BusinessService : IChargable<ServiceCharge>
{
    public ServiceCharge Charge()
    {
        return new ServiceCharge(...
    }
}

class Product : IChargable<Sale>
{
    public Sale Charge()
    {
        return new Sale(...
    }
}
```

which means some code like this would work

```
var chargables = new IChargable<Transaction>[]
    {
        new BusinessService(),
        new Product()
    };

var transactions = chargables.Select(c => c.Charge());
```

Comment: In order for that to work, the declared return type of `IChargable<T>.Charge` should be `T` instead of `Transaction`.

Comment: @JeanHominal, but there is no `T` type. `T` is contstrained to be polymorphic with `Transaction`. The code does work, because `IChargable` is covariant for `T`.

Comment: @JeanHominal, You cannot declare a variable with the name of a type parameter unless it happens to be a valid type (unlikely for `T` and not in the question.)

Comment: I know that there is no `T` type, because `T` is a type parameter, not a type. But still, you can use either types or type parameters for type declarations - whether of method parameter, field and property types, or method return types. Seriously, you can try and compile the gist [I wrote](https://gist.github.com/jhominal/6018805), e.g. on the http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php website. Between @p.s.w.g and you, we have two halves of an optimal generic interface declaration - but he did not add covariance when he could, and you do not use the genericity.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It's more general and it will be handy for way more scenarios, but I didn't chose it just because an interface is just all I needed for now, and I'm triying to maintain my code as simple as possible (Clean Code). But I keep your idea on mind if my code gets more complex :)